# TimeoutInterval in Alamofire

Tags: ios, alamofire

If I set an 5 mins timeout interval for Alamofire request like below, it means an individual/overall API sync would take 5 mins?

```
sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300
self.defaultManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: sessionConfiguration, serverTrustPolicyManager: policyManager)
```

Comment: No, it means that max time for timeout response is 300 seconds. If API finishes earlier you won't have to wait that much

Comment: Thanks. Also, can you please tell me, whether an each API call would take max timeout interval? or an overall API would take max timeout interval?

Comment: I posted answers to your question as an answer - if you find it helpful accept it, if you have other questions - just shoot

Answer (score 0):

No, it means that max time for timeout response is 300 seconds. If API finishes earlier you won't have to wait that much.

Regarding second question -  it depends on your backend. For most cases 60 seconds is more then enough, however if you have any call that exceed it then you need to increase it. Note that it doesn't take parsing time into the consideration, just getting response from server. If you have large object that needs x minutes to parse but get it in 50 seconds it will be fine.

The main reason for timeout is because your server might never response and instead of letting your app hang, you can handle timeout error somehow.

Comment: Thanks. But, I think, you have misunderstood my question or I didn't phrased properly. My second question is, 'If I have an 10 API calls, whether each API call would have an 5 mins timeout or overall it would take 5 mins for an 10 API call?

Comment: If you run them in paralel, at the same time it would take 5 mins. If you go one by one, it would take 50 mins.